# Why the expired css style still cached rather than requesting from server?

Tags: caching

I visit [this page](http://m.58.com/bj/zufang/?58ihm=m_house_index_zufang&58cid=1&PGTID=0d200001-0000-15fd-aae2-e605031f9c08&ClickID=1) twice by clicking enter key in address bar in chrome. The css file seems expired: cache-control max-age is 5 days, but last-modified is 5 days ago(I'm in China and now the time is Oct. 24 2016 12:16 PM). Thanks in advance.

[image]

The whole request headers:

```
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8
Host:c.58cdn.com.cn
Proxy-Connection:keep-alive
Referer:http://m.58.com/bj/zufang/?58ihm=m_house_index_zufang&58cid=1&PGTID=0d200001-0000-15fd-aae2-e605031f9c08&ClickID=1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1
```

And the whole reponse headers:

```
Age:69061
Cache-Control:max-age=432000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Wed, 23 Nov 2016 08:43:18 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 18 Nov 2016 08:38:39 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Cache:HIT from www.matocloud.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know why the `last-modified` doesn't work - `cache-control` has the higher priority over `last-modified`.

So if I visit the css earlier in 5 days, browser will always load it from cache, which is exactly `cache-control` 's purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the GMT time zone of the Last-Modified field. This is different from your local timezone.

The Last-Modified field has the time `08:38:39 GMT`. However, the current time is only `04:22:54 GMT`.

You can here the current GMT time here: http://time.is/GMT

EDIT: The Date field in your response header is not accurate for some reason. The time has not yet reached `08:43:18 GMT`.

Comment: The date field is static whenever I refresh the page even with "crtil+F5". 

The GMT is `24 Nov 2016 04:29 GMT`, but still 5 days+ later than `18 Nov 2016 08:38:39 GMT`, isn't it true? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because of the if-modified-since effect.
Browser sends request to the cache server and cache requests with if-modified-since and server sends OK so the cache directly sends with hit xcache header